# MacBook Air not booting up with a black screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, catalina

I have a MacBook Air (2014 Model) and facing a bit of weird problem here. I had plugged in my Mac and kept a huge file for download and locked the screen, (the disk might have actually run out of space.) After I while I saw a question symbol hovering over the screen and I tried to force restart my Mac. But the problem is after the restart, my Mac won't boot. It just throws me a black/grey screen with the apple chime every time I restart.  I am not able to enter the recovery mode or safe mode either.  I tried creating an external bootable drive but my Mac would still show me a black screen when I press the options button while booting.  I tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC controller but still no change. Can anyone help me with fixing this problem?

I was wondering could this be a problem with the Hardware/SSD problem or it could be a firmware issue. (I recently upgraded the MBAto OS X Catalina).